# No se ejecuta Jupyter desde Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, anaconda, anaconda3

hoy instale anaconda para programar con python pero a la hora de ejecutar jupyter para programar me da este fallo:

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 836, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 86, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2037, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1711, in init_webapp
    success = self._bind_http_server()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1718, in _bind_http_server
    return self._bind_http_server_unix() if self.sock else self._bind_http_server_tcp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1744, in _bind_http_server_tcp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Estoy usando Anaconda3
Sabeis a que se puede deber el error?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione el error.
Este error ocurre si no indicas la ip y el puerto.

el codigo seria tal que asi:

```
jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

como veis especificamos la ip y tambien el puerto.